# HTML5 Geolocation API to Obtain WiFi AC Information?

Tags: html, macos, api, geolocation, wifi

I am trying to create an application in HTML5 that attempts to determine a list of Wifi access points in range of the user's device. I've done some research and discovered that Google's geolocation API sends a

> "computer’s IP address and a collection of information of [its]
>   surrounding Wi-Fi access points to their default location service
>   provider (e.g., Google Location Services..."

I have yet to find, however, any resources that look into if the possibility of obtaining information such as SSID, MAC address, etc for a developer using the API. Is this possible, and if so, could you redirect me to another source or explain how to retrieve them? Even the documentation for the API does not specify how to retrieve the information that Google uses to determine geolocation. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[Article for above quote](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/04/11/geolocation/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no public API to retrieve the SSID, MAC address in HTML5. It is being implemented inside the browser to pass it to the location service provider.

You can only get the information unless you wrote your own native application.